# Jquery selector not working on content loaded through ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors

I am having below code to send the value of radio button people have clicked via ajax. But it however only works on the first set of options I give. After the the user press next link and all the options are changed and new one loaeded through ajax. But on that this selector is not working.

```
$(".options input").click(function(){
var ans = $(this).val();

$.post("sessions", { action: "set_answer", answer: ans, question: qid  },
function(data) {
 alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});


});
```

What is the possible solution? Below is how the options are.

```
<div class="options">
<input id="1"type="radio" name="answer"  value="Two" />Two<br/>
<input id="2"type="radio" name="answer"  value="One"  />One<br/>
<input id="3"type="radio" name="answer"  value="Four"  />Four<br/>
<input id="4"type="radio" name="answer"  value="Five"  />Five<br/>
<input id="5"type="radio" name="answer"  value="Six"  />Six<br/>    
</div>
```

Comment: please post more details like whats the next link  and how are the optiosn changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If latest jQuery,

```
$('.options input').on('click', function(event) {
....
```

Or you could try doing:

```
$(".options input").live("click", function(){
....
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 5):

If jQuery 1.7+,try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.options', function(){
   if ($(e.target).is('input')) {
      var ans =  $(this).val();

      $.post("sessions", { action: "set_answer", answer: ans, question: qid  }, function(data) {
         alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
      });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The selector isn't working because the elements that you are trying to access don't exist at the point you are creating them.

To do this you should use [Jquery On](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event handler. This will select elements across the entire document even if you create them pro-grammatically later on as in the case of Ajax.

Usage (untested):

```
$(".options input").on("click", function(event){
    var ans = $(this).val();

    $.post("sessions", { action: "set_answer", answer: ans, question: qid  },
    function(data) {
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });

});
```