# Detecting a click on a link in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've just started learning jQuery and I'm completely lost..

I created a list which has pictures of cats, when I click on one I want to copy the clicked image to another div. However, I'm already stuck on getting the click event. I've tested it on multiple other lists wicht links with pictures and I didn't have any problem with those.

The message should show when I click on a cat, but I can't get it to work properly.

The HTML:

```
<div id="cats">
    <div class="catTrack">
        <ul id="catItems">
            <li class="catGrid">
                <div class="catItem">
                    <a href="#" id="1">
                        <img src="cat.png">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#catItems li .catItem a").click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('Clicked a cat!');
    });
});
```

**Edit:**

The selector is not detected because I'm using a script load the code into `<div id="cats">`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cats").load("get_cats.php");
});
```

**Edit 2:**

Found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9426290/3677329

Final script:

```
$(document).on('click', '#catItems li .catItem a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Clicked a cat!');
});
```

Comment: why do you have this? `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: You forgot to send the handler.. `$("#catItems li .CatItem a").click(function(event)`

Comment: @Niang I added that to prevent the browser from scrolling up when the link is clicked, it wasn't preventing my code and I fixed the event handler ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a typo, the className is `catItem` with a lowercase `c`, classNames are case sensitive

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#catItems li .catItem a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('Clicked a cat!');
    });
});
```

And if you want to use the `event` parameter, most browser requires you to add it as an argument

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Epm8F/)

Comment: Somehow the code seems to work but when I implement the same solution on my larger piece of code, the click event is not detected and the browser scrolls back up. The only thing that's different are the names and the link has 3 extra attributes.

Comment: Then you're not using the correct selector. Try something simple like `$('selector').css('color','red')` to see if you're targeting the correct element, and then add the click handler when you've found a selector that works for you.

Comment: That's a beautiful solution. It's not detecting the selector because I'm using `.load()` to fill the #cats div. I'm guessing this is because it takes a second or two and the javascript is using `$(document).ready`. How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Look up event delegation.that is, you hookup the event on a parent element but you handle only events for the elements you care about

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code: and demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/zrd8c/

- (nothing related but) you have no end tag for `img`  => `<img src="cat.png"/>`
- `.CatItem` should be `.catItem`
- You have `event.preventDefault` but `event` was missing from the `function` => `function(e)`

`:)`

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#catItems li .catItem a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Clicked a cat!');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove this `event.preventDefault();` this will prevent your code to work, but you can have it if you want but with different approach, but first try to remove it and see your code works.

Answer (score -1):

### The concept

When click a cat, replace a div with it.

### The error

You writed `CatItem` instead `catItem`.

### JSFiddle [(link)](http://jsfiddle.net/Epm8F/1/)

#### HTML example

```
<div id="cats">
    <div class="catTrack">
        <ul id="catItems">
            <li class="catGrid">
                <div class="catItem">
                    <a href="#" id="1">
                        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgLe7.gif?s=32&g=1" />
                         <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/cf617afb80769f89ec7e217d135be7e5?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="replaced">Another div</div>
```

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".catItem img").click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        url = $(this).attr('src')
        $("#replaced").html("<img src="+url+"/>");
    });
});
```

Enjoy (: